# Wrong password when importing user into Firebase (password_hash using SHA256)

Tags: python, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-admin

We are migrating users into Firebase Auth from an external database using password hashed with SHA256.

We currently try `from firebase_admin import auth` to import the users. We are able to import an example user, but not able to login with the user (wrong password).

Here are the minimal code snippets to reproduce the issue.

1. We use a user as an example
2. We use sha256 to hash password
3. Run `import_users_to_firebase()`
4. Try to login with the example user -> invalid password

`

```
def hash_password(raw_password):
    import base64
    import hashlib
    algo = hashlib.sha256()
    algo.update(raw_password)
    return base64.b64encode(algo.digest())

def create_mock_user_data():
    email = 'test@example.com'
    password = 'test@example.com'
    password_hash = hash_password(password)
    print 'password_hash: {}'.format(password_hash)
    return email, password_hash


def import_users_to_firebase():
    mock_email, mock_password_hash = create_mock_user_data()
    users = [
        auth.ImportUserRecord(
            uid='someuid',
            display_name='Test example',
            email=mock_email,
            email_verified=False,
            password_hash=b'{}'.format(mock_password_hash),
        ),
        # users list can contain up to 1000 records
    ]
    hash_alg = auth.UserImportHash.sha256(rounds=0)
    result = auth.import_users(users, hash_alg=hash_alg)

    print('Successfully imported {0} users. Failed to import {1} users.'.format(
    result.success_count, result.failure_count))

    for err in result.errors:
        print('Failed to import {0} due to {1}'.format(
            users[err.index].uid, err.reason))
```

`

Am I missing something or misunderstanding something here?

Is there a way that I can check the password_hash is imported correctly? Or is there a way that I can config which hashing algorithm Firebase is using so that the imported password would match the example user login?

Comment: Passwords aren't just hashed, they are also salted. Otherwise someone could use a rainbow table with precalculated hashes and break all passwords simply by looking up the password hash

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many thanks to the Firebase Support team, I got my problem solved:) 
The trick is don't do base64 encode in the hash_password() or decode it afterward so it is a raw bytes sequence. That is

```
auth.ImportUserRecord(
    uid='someuid',
    display_name='Test example',
    email=mock_email,
    email_verified=False,
    password_hash=mock_password_hash, # <-- mock_password_hash is not base64 encoded
)
```